# Import multiple .xlsx files & perform arithmetic operation with data operated data write in single new xlsx file with multiple sheet using openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsx

'''
I am using openpyxl to open one xlsx file & making few arithmetic operation then the saving it in new xlsx file. Now that i want to import many files and want to operate same things and store all file results in single xlsx file multiple sheet.
'''

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl
wb= openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\server\Desktop\Python\Data.xlsx", read_only=True)
 # resading file from
ws = wb['Sheet1'] # moving into sheet1
# Comprehension
row_data = [  [cell.value for cell in row] for row in ws.rows] # looping through row data in sheet
header_data = row_data[0] # leaving header data by slicing
row_data = row_data[1:] #storing xlsx file data into 2D list

[ dp.append(dp[1]*dp[2])for dp in row_data] # perfornming multplication opertion columnwise, lets say coulmn 1 * column 2 in a row_data and appending into next column
wb.close()# closing the worksheet

wb = openpyxl.Workbook() # opening new worksheet 
ws = wb.active # sheet 1 is active`enter code here`
ws.append(header_data) # header data writtten
for row in row_data: # 2D list data is writng in sheet 1
    ws.append(row)
wb.save(r"C:\Users\server\Desktop\Python\Result.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and what is going wrong with it. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: thanks, Can you please review below code, which i tried.

Answer (score 0):

'''I am able store multiple xlsx files in a list, Now i want to access each file data and perform few arithmetic operation , finally results data need to store in single xlsx file with multiple sheets in it 
'''

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl
import os 

location=r"C:\Users\server\Desktop\Python\Data.xlsx" # will get folder location here where many xlsx files are present
counter = 0 #keep a count of all files found
xlsx_files = [] #list to store all xlsx files found at location

for file in os.listdir(wb):
    try:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            print ("xlsx file found:\t", file)
            xlsx_files.append(str(file))
            counter = counter+1


    except Exception as e:
        raise e
        print ("No files found here!")

print ("Total files found:\t", counter)
```

Comment: Can someone please suggest some methods! it would be great help

Comment: What is the question? You can open each workbook with the load_workbook method.

Comment: Yes, I can open each workbook in above code, Now i need to open multiple xlsx file from folder which has data and with this data  want to perform the few operation with data, and the results of data need to written in single xlsx file in multiple xlsx sheet. Can you please look at it.